# Setting temporary defaults for plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I'm making a series of plots such as:

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(20,5))

#First Batch of plots
axes[0].hist(...)
axes[1].hist(...)
axes[2].hist(...)

#Second Batch of plots
axes[0].hist(...)
axes[1].hist(...)
axes[2].hist(...)

#Third Batch of plots
axes[0].hist(...)
axes[1].hist(...)
axes[2].hist(...)


plt.show()
```

and I want all the plots in a single batch to have the same style (e.g. the same label, the same color,...) I can manually go and add these to the `.hist` command, but is there a way to set a 'temporary default' that will make the style of each batch of plots the same?

Comment: If you mean that you have a lot of keywords that are repeated in each call to `hist`, you could define a dict of keywords beforehand, say `my_style = dict(...)` and then pass that dict to the `hist` call as `ax.hist(..., **my_style)`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to define a dict with the arguments and pass it to each call:

```
kwargs = dict(lw=3, c='C2', ls='--')

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot([0, 1], **kwargs)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot([1, 0], **kwargs)
```

[image]